# WSO2 IS Request is unparsable, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to integrate my service with WSO2 identity server. I found scim2 API, that aplly creates users by rest requset. The sample request is:

```
{
    "schemas": [],
    "name": {
        "familyName": "resttest@gmail.com",
        "givenName": "RestTest"
    },
    "userName": "resttest@gmail.com",
    "password": "admin",
    "emails": [{
            "primary": true,
            "value": "resttest@gmail.com",
            "type": "home"
        }
    ]
}
```

but I get response:

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
    ],
    "scimType": "invalidSyntax",
    "detail": "Request is unparsable, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.",
    "status": "400"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? I can't find helpful information in the logs. The only one line from the logs below:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.charon3.core.encoder.JSONDecoder} - json error in decoding the resource
```

Comment: What is the IS version that you use?

Comment: Seems there is no issue with the payload. Are you executing a curl command? If so please add the curl command into the question (masking sensitive data/credentials). If you are using a curl command mention the OS as well. Otherwise what is the HTTP client that you use for this request

Comment: Problem found. It was postman bug. It set Content-length = zero to all my requests. restart help me.
Thank all for answers!

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** My answer is based on thinking that you have initiated a curl.

Seems Like there is an issue with the encoding. I have tried this with the IS 6.0.0 with the following curl (exported it from the postman) and it worked.

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' --data-raw '{
"schemas": [],
"name": {
    "familyName": "resttest@gmail.com",
    "givenName": "RestTest"
},
"userName": "resttest@gmail.com",
"password": "admin",
"emails": [{
        "primary": true,
        "value": "resttest@gmail.com",
        "type": "home"
    }
]}'
```

Here note that I have used admin credentials to create the user request. You can change the request auth as you need.

To validate your Curl you can import your curl request from the PostMan and check whether you receive the correct payload as expected in your question.